# Routing to another screen after hitting the sign up button

Tags: flutter, function, dart, authentication, aws-amplify

Hello Flutter Developers. I have this issue which I need help with. I have created a sign up function in my code and I want it to be that when a user hit the sign up button it routes to the confirmation screen. Here's how the function is...

```
Future<void> signIn() async {
    try {
      final userAttribute = <CognitoUserAttributeKey, String>{
        CognitoUserAttributeKey.email: _emailController.text,
      };

      final res = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
        username: _usernameController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
        options: CognitoSignUpOptions(userAttributes: userAttribute),
      );

      setState(() {
        isSignedIn = res.isSignUpComplete;
      });
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('$e', style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 16.0,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      );
    }
  }
```

and this is how the sign up button looks

```
Container(
              height: 40.0,
              width: 140.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
              ),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: signIn,
                child: Text(
                  'Sign In',
                  style: GoogleFonts.frijole(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Anyone please help me I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Container(
              height: 40.0,
              width: 140.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
              ),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed:    showPlatformDialog(
                      context: this.context,
                      builder: (context) => BasicDialogAlert(
                        title: Text("Are you sure?"),

                        actions: <Widget>[
                          BasicDialogAction(
                            title: Text("cancel"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                          ),
                          BasicDialogAction(
                            title: Text("ok"),
                            onPressed: () {
                             signIn();
                            },
                          ),

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                child: Text(
                  'Sign In',
                  style: GoogleFonts.frijole(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

And after **setState()**,add this line:

```
   Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => profile_page()
      )
```